What would happen if the atmosphere disappeared for a fraction of a second?
What would be the effects if the entirety of Earth's atmosphere disappeared for a fraction of a second - barely enough time to be noticeable, and then reappeared?  It would be gone for only a very small amount of time, but enough that a picture could be accidentally captured of it.  Would there be lasting effects to Earth or momentary effects?  Would we notice anything was wrong, if it was only gone for that short a period of time?

"Noticeable" is an important detail here.  And also "entirety".  Judging the extent of the atmosphere is tricky - do you include clouds, with their ice crystals and condensed vapour, or just gases?  Do you include the contents of respiring individuals' lungs?  Is every atom magically put back in place where it was and with the vectors it had when it vanished?

I'm also going to refer you, as a brand new member of the forum, to the Sandbox. This is a place for members, especially new ones, to get help with question writing skills! Jdunlop brings up some good points and these sorts of considerations can mean the difference between getting a helpful answer and getting an answer that has nothing to do with what you really want to ask!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Welcome to worldbuilding. Please read our [help]: you will find clearly stated there that questions along the line of "what if X happened?" are not a good fit for us.

As @jdunlop said, without a definition of "noticeable" this is unanswerable.  Also, given the number of video cameras in operation worldwide at any given moment, there will either be zero images or many images.

I try not to vote to close new user questions, but this has already led to one answer with too many errors. VTC:Needs More Details for my part. But, (a) What does "lasting effects to Earth" mean to you? The [help/dont-ask] describes the Book Rule, meaning if your question is too broad it's out of scope for Stack Exchange. An open-ended "anything that might happen" question is inappropriate here. (b) You're allowed to ask one and only one question. You're asking at least two. (c) Is the atmo inside controlled spaces also gone? Planes? Submarines? Hermetically sealed buildings? Etc. Etc. Etc.

Please carefully read the [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and [ask] to better understand the limits of Stack Exchange. And I fully second @elemtilas. There's one or more great worldbuilding questions here, but how a question is asked is really important on Stack Exchange (especially on Worldbuilding), so please consider using our Sandbox.

What is of course not clear is the time interval requested. As the question asks for some kind of result, it must be some interval of time. The only instruction given is "bearly enough time to be noticeable"
The average human reaction time is apparently 250 milliseconds or 0.25s. Exceptional humans exist of course, and we can get below 0.2s, but lets assume the question is about the everyday person.
The other metric given is "accidentally captured" (on camera), the average camera shutter speed is 1/60th of a second. This is 0.0166s or 16.6ms. This would be reasonable to catch something occuring in a 0.2s time window accidentally, just from the sheer amount of selfies.
What is very clear is that this interval of time is based entirely on the event "atmosphere disappearing and reappearing" and has nothing to do with the after effects of this event.

As mentioned, explosive decompression. (Timeframe 0.1-0.5s required)


Ruptured eardrums, lung damage, nitrogen bubbles in bloodstream, fatal embolisms, pressure related injuries...
Any structure not designed for that level of stress will be damaged.
A shockwave unless the "reappear" was perfect in every way.


A short "burst" of full Radiation exposure without any ozone or air layer to stop it from reaching us. Cosmic rays and radiation are basically traveling at lightspeed. So the timeframe here depends on the height of the atmosphere. Using 10,000km the timeframe is 0.033s. I point out that the very top of the atmosphere is not really stopping the rays much so this time interval is probably much lower, making it more likely. Not sure how it would affect biologicals, electronics seem likely to survive a short burst. Though you'd have to account for the magnetic field.

Anything in the water near the surface would be... unhappy, as the water "boiled" for that fraction of a second, probably would hurt surface algae?

(This seems unlikely now) The burst of full radiation might fry every unshielded electronic device assuming that it reaches the surface. I think even if the rays and radiation were caught by the atmosphere part way.

Planes would plummet for this period of time, though It is possible that they might explode due to the pressure difference. (Timeframe 0.5s or less, varies, might be okay)

There would be a lot of selfies with a perfectly clear black sky, free of clouds, with full stars on display.



All physical phenomena need some minimum amount of time. For an eardrum to rupture the exposure to the pressure differential must be longer than the amount needed for its propagation across the membrane; this can be estimated, and you can then set an upper limit to the "fraction of a second - barely enough time to be noticeable". In other words, this answer lists a series of thing which might happen, but then they may not, depending on how long the phenomenon lasts.

@AlexP I agree, I explained how I agree in more detail. "Barely enough time to be noticeable" for humans is 200-250ms. The camera example would average at 16.6ms. These are speeds where explosions can readily occur. I think eardrums would be unhappy.

In particular, electronic devices would not even notice there was a burst of radiation. Most of the charged particles are deflected by  the magnetosphere, and the amount of non-charged (i.e. X and gamma rays, since there are few neutrons in solar wind) ones to reach the surface in a fraction of a second is utterly negligible. Consider multiple-hour international flights well above the bulk of the atmosphere, where the electronics survives just fine - and the plastic windows do not shield much against X and gamma rays. Even considering major solar storms, the effect would be insignificant.

@RadovanGarabík I just assumed that airplanes were designed to withstand lightning strikes and radiation. But yeah valid point about the magnetic field.

@Wyrsa Lightning yes (esp. aircraft made from composites, where it has to be designed, as opposed to the "traditional" metal frame, where it comes for free), and while cosmic rays  are not completely insignificant up there, see how your average mobile phone (that has definitely not been designed to withstand more radiation than usual) survives just fine.

(1) is wrong. "Explosive decompression" is the transition event covered by "disappeared for a fraction of a second." It's magically gone, leaving a vacuum, for a fraction of a second. (2) is over stated. (3) Is also overstated. Even in a vacuum, it takes water time to boil and the vacuum is only there for a fraction of a second. (4) Is definitely overstated (I'm an EE...). (5) Is wrong. Planes would possibly experience a moment of turbulence, but that depends more on how the air is brought back. (6) Is completely wrong. Fraction of a second!

More to the point, please don't answer poorly asked questions. See [answer] for more details.
